# Character::IsEmoji not working for Characters with numbers in them?

Tags: java, java-21

I have a Java 21 app where I want to determine if a string has an emoji. I am using the newly created Emoji API from Java 21 but every time I have an input String containing a number like "123" Character::isEmoji() returns true. I have been using this as a resource: https://inside.java/2023/11/20/sip089/

This is the code I have been using:

```java
  private boolean containsEmoji(String s) {
    return s.codePoints().anyMatch(Character::isEmoji);
  }
```

For example:

```java
System.out.println(
        "123".codePoints().anyMatch( Character :: isEmoji )
);
```

> true

And also:

```java
  private boolean containsEmoji(String s) {
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      int codePoint = s.codePointAt(i);
      if (Character.isEmoji(codePoint)) {
        return true;
      }
    } 
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Wow, I am surprised and confused. Even "1" returns true, but "x" returns false.

Comment: I am looking at the [Unicode documentation](https://unicode.org/reports/tr51/#Emoji_Properties_and_Data_Files) linked by the `Character#isEmoji` Javadoc. But I do not see an explanation.

Comment: Your title is not an accurate description of the issue. Needs an edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Those digits are emoji, technically

Yes, digits 0-9 in the [Basic Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)) (US-ASCII) block of Unicode are considered to be Emoji, for reasons that escape me.

Follow the trail of documentation:

1. Javadoc for [`Character.isEmoji`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isEmoji(int))
2. [*Unicode Emoji (Technical Standard #51)*](https://unicode.org/reports/tr51/#Emoji_Properties_and_Data_Files)
3. [emoji-data](https://unicode.org/reports/tr51/#emoji_data)
4. [*emoji-data.txt*](https://www.unicode.org/Public/15.1.0/ucd/emoji/emoji-data.txt) (for *Emoji Version 15.1*)

… lists:

> 0030..0039    ; Emoji                # E0.0  [10] (0️..9️)    digit zero..digit nine

Section *1.5.2 Versioning* of [the Unicode page](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/tr51-23.html) explains comment `E0.0` as:

> This label is used for special characters, including:
>
> • Most emoji component characters, regardless of when they were first encoded.
>
> • Other non-emoji characters in the data files.

… which confounds me.

But it seems to me that **`Character.isEmoji` reporting plain digits as being emoji is a feature**, not a bug.

### Use `Charater.isEmojiPresentation`

To determine if a character is what we more commonly think of as an emoji, use another method on `Character` class: [`Charater.isEmojiPresentation`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isEmojiPresentation(int)). That method returns `false` for the code points of the Basic Latin digits.

Comment: It looks like they're emoji because they can be used as combining characters for the keycap emoji (1️⃣ etc al.). Surprising!

Comment: Being an emoji implies that you can request an emoji presentation, e.g. `"\u0030\uFE0F"`, for a zero digit rendered as an emoji (if the font/rendering environment has such an alternative presentation) is a valid character (or grapheme).

Comment: You can, by the way, use `Character.isEmojiPresentation(…)` to check whether the character would be rendered as emoji or text by default. For, e.g. `#`, `*`, `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `©`, `®`, it returns `false` so these are rather text characters which *can* be rendered as emoji when requested.

Comment: @Holger I added your point to Answer. Thank you.